# Objective-c Completion handler to Delphi

Tags: ios, objective-c, delphi, firemonkey

In Objective-c header I have this :

```
- (void)offerForConstraints:(RTCMediaConstraints *)constraints
          completionHandler:(nullable void (^)(RTCSessionDescription *_Nullable sdp,
                                               NSError *_Nullable error))completionHandler;
```

That I translate like this:

```
type

  TWebRTCPeerConnectionOfferForConstraintsCompletionHandler = 
    procedure(sdp: RTCSessionDescription; error: NSError) of object;

procedure offerForConstraints(
  constraints: RTCMediaConstraints; 
  completionHandler: TWebRTCPeerConnectionOfferForConstraintsCompletionHandler); cdecl;
```

But every time I call `offerForConstraints` I Have :

> **Access violation** at address 0000000183398910, accessing address
>   000000004D555468 At address: $0000000183398910 (**objc_msgSend** + 16)

sometimes I also have this error:

> -[__NSCFDictionary offerForConstraints:completionHandler:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c0271b40

or this one:

> -[_CFXNotificationObserverRegistration offerForConstraints:completionHandler:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x1c4273a40

Any idea what going wrong?

Comment: A more complete example might help. You're not showing how you're calling offerForConstraints, nor what you are passing for completionHandler.

Comment: AFAIK, a "procedure **of object**" is not compatible as a *direct* callback for an Objective-C API. You will need to use a suitable wrapper procedure of proper signature and have it then call your object `procedure` internally.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Do you have an example of such wrapper?